# mc update 4.8.25 changed folder of shell commands

Tags: mc

I updated **mc** and all shell commands disappeared.
I couldn't execute openoffice or other command from mc.
I checked ~/.config/mc/mc.ext and found that the folder of doc.sh was in /usr/lib/mc.

Answer (score 0):

Then I've checked /usr/lib and found that they moved from /usr/lib to /usr/libexec